# Gamedev Birthday Celebration

Tags: discussion

Did you know that Game Development's birthday was on **October 21st**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”